# Is it possible to programmatically generate a DbContext instead of an ObjectContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am interested in programmatically regenerating the entities that map to our database whenever the database is updated. Following instructions and links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I am able to accomplish this, but I can't figure out how to programmatically generate a class that inherits from DbContext instead of ObjectContext. Is there any way to do this?

It looks as though an EDMX file (which currently doesn't exist in my solution) is required to use the EF 5.X DbContext Generator, so maybe I'm approaching this in the wrong way.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: In VS2012 EdmGen generates DbContexts. Alternatives are [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) or [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838).

Comment: @Gert Thanks for the tip. I ended up just passing the ObjectContext into my DbContext's constructor, then using dbContext.Set<MyType>() to access my entities.